# Site mailbox end of life?

Tags: site-mailboxes

I know that you can't create new site mailboxes in SPO so my clients were forced down the Office 365 group. I've seen the migration tool for distribution lists to Office 365 groups. But what's happening to existing site mailboxes? I'm guessing that there isn't a migration path to Office 365 groups because site mailboxes have more features than Office 365 conversations - specifically for my client - sub-folders. They couldn't be migrated without loosing the sub-folders which is sub-optimal and not great from an auditing point of view (pharma industry).

Has Microsoft said anything about end of life for existing site mailboxes? My client is slowly moving to Office 365 groups for new projects and we **could** archive each old mailbox into a PST in case the email is needed in future but that's a tedious job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, Microsoft has announced in January 2017 that they are removing Site Mailboxes from Office 365, and they are recommending everyone to use Office 365 Groups instead of the regular site mailbox.

They have also announced that they are working on a migration tool / process that will help you in the transition from Site mailbox to Office 365 Groups. Though they have not announced an exact date when this tool will be available for all the users, they have announced that it should be available before the end of 2017. And to everyone’s relief, all the functionalities of the existing site mailboxes will work normally for the time being and they have not announced any time frame when the support for existing site mailboxes will be removed / stopped completely.

You can refer the following articles for more information regarding the Site mailbox termination,

[**https://www.petri.com/office-365-drops-site-mailboxes**](https://www.petri.com/office-365-drops-site-mailboxes)
**practical365.com/collaboration/groups/site-mailboxes-sunset/**